# how to handle missing data in my JSON to get the right JSON

Tags: json, jmeter

how to handle missing data in my JSON to get the right  JSON

{"action":"executeaction","params":{"actionname":"Service.ACT_Show_LanguagePage","applyto":"selection","guids":"${guid}"},"changes":{},"objects":[{"attributes":{"PassportType":{"value":null},"AppType":{"readonly":true,"value":null},"AppDate":{"readonly":true,"value":null},"PayTime":{"value":null},"Service.Application_CaptchaImage":{"readonly":true,"value":null},"Relation":{"value":null},"IsCaptchaMatched":{"readonly":true,"value":false},"LOV.GeneralInstructions_Application":{"readonly":true,"value":null},"TotalFees":{"readonly":true,"value":null},"Service.Application_Person_Guardian":{"readonly":true,"value":null},"EndorsementInd":{"value":false},"Service.PaymentOrder_Application":{"readonly":true,"value":null},"Service.Barcode_Application":{"readonly":true,"value":null},"AppNo":{"readonly":true,"value":null},"Service.FormDocument_Application":{"readonly":true,"value":null},"FeesPaid":{"readonly":true,"value":"No"},"Service.Application_Person":{"value":null},"RenewReason":{"value":null},"Accredited":{"readonly":true,"value":false},"ServiceCategory":{"value":null},"IsApproved":{"value":false},"ApplicantAge":{"value":"0"},"SubmittedLocation":{"value":null},"Service.Application_Instrument":{"value":null},"LOV.SupportingDocuments_Application":{"readonly":true,"value":null},"PaymentMethod":{"readonly":true,"value":null},"CaptchaInput":{"value":null}},"guid":"${guid}","hash":"${hash}":"Service.Application"}],"context":[],"profiledata":{"1673510999499-1":61,"1673510999884-2":24,"1673510999911-3":12}}

Answer (score 0):

How do we know which JSON should be "right" and what "data" is "missing"?

Here is the problematic place:

[image]

you need to either remove lines:

```
:
"Service.Application"
```

or add a comma after `"hash": "${hash}",` and populate the "Service.Application" attribute with the correct value.

You can use online JSON formatters/validators like https://jsonlint.com/ or try parsing JSON using [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) and [JsonSlurper](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) - the parser will tell you the line number and the related problem

Here is a valid JSON with "Service.Application" attribute removed:

```
{
  "action": "executeaction",
  "params": {
    "actionname": "Service.ACT_Show_LanguagePage",
    "applyto": "selection",
    "guids": "${guid}"
  },
  "changes": {},
  "objects": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "PassportType": {
          "value": null
        },
        "AppType": {
          "readonly": true,
          "value": null
        },
        "AppDate": {
          "readonly": true,
          "value": null
        },
        "PayTime": {
          "value": null
        },
        "Service.Application_CaptchaImage": {
          "readonly": true,
          "value": null
        },
        "Relation": {
          "value": null
        },
        "IsCaptchaMatched": {
          "readonly": true,
          "value": false
        },
        "LOV.GeneralInstructions_Application": {
          "readonly": true,
          "value": null
        },
        "TotalFees": {
          "readonly": true,
          "value": null
        },
        "Service.Application_Person_Guardian": {
          "readonly": true,
          "value": null
        },
        "EndorsementInd": {
          "value": false
        },
        "Service.PaymentOrder_Application": {
          "readonly": true,
          "value": null
        },
        "Service.Barcode_Application": {
          "readonly": true,
          "value": null
        },
        "AppNo": {
          "readonly": true,
          "value": null
        },
        "Service.FormDocument_Application": {
          "readonly": true,
          "value": null
        },
        "FeesPaid": {
          "readonly": true,
          "value": "No"
        },
        "Service.Application_Person": {
          "value": null
        },
        "RenewReason": {
          "value": null
        },
        "Accredited": {
          "readonly": true,
          "value": false
        },
        "ServiceCategory": {
          "value": null
        },
        "IsApproved": {
          "value": false
        },
        "ApplicantAge": {
          "value": "0"
        },
        "SubmittedLocation": {
          "value": null
        },
        "Service.Application_Instrument": {
          "value": null
        },
        "LOV.SupportingDocuments_Application": {
          "readonly": true,
          "value": null
        },
        "PaymentMethod": {
          "readonly": true,
          "value": null
        },
        "CaptchaInput": {
          "value": null
        }
      },
      "guid": "${guid}",
      "hash": "${hash}"
    }
  ],
  "context": [],
  "profiledata": {
    "1673510999499-1": 61,
    "1673510999884-2": 24,
    "1673510999911-3": 12
  }
}
```